# How To Test a MIME Multipart URL?

Tags: mime

I'm trying to test a MIME Multipart URL. Is it sufficient enough to do a simple html form and submit a file to it like this?

```
<html>
<body>
<FORM action="<MIME Multipart URL>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
<p>file <INPUT type="file" name="file"><BR>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do this I get a file back called multipart. The contents of the file contains an error though so I was wondering if I'm not doing something right with the submission mechanism or if I'm just not submitting the right values in my file.

FILE CONTENTS

POST /core/eligibility HTTP/1.1

Host: server_host:server_port

Content-Length: 1354

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=XbCY

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“PayloadType“

blahblah

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“ProcessingMode"

blahblah

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“PayloadID"

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“TimeStamp"

2007-08-30T10:20:34Z

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“UserName"

blahblah

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“Password"

blahblah

--XbCY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“SenderID"

blahblah

--XbCY Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“ReceiverID"

blahblah

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“CORERuleVersion"

blahblah

--XbCY

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“Payload"

payload blahblah

--XbCY--

Answer (score 0):

Build list of content items. Submission will build form-data entries as in file.

```
<FORM action="<MIME Multipart URL>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
PayloadID<INPUT type="text" name="PayloadID"><br />
  : (other items) :
<INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
</FORM>
```